# Legend for two aesthetics and geom_abline in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to prepare a legend for the following plot, with dotted followed by A and dashed followed by B. It is not showing correctly. As I have 2 aesthetic, it sometimes show only one line type or sometimes, nothing. I've used `scale_linetype_manual()` and `guides()`, however it was not able to produce the desired effect. But

The code that I've created, I've remove the code that showing my attempts of making a legend.

```
exemplo<-data.frame(Location = c("Tiburon Peninsula", "San Francisco","Santa Barbara area", "Santa Monica Mountains", "Marin County", 
                             "Santa Cruz Mountains", "Monterey County", "San Diego County","California Coast"),
                Area = c(5.9, 45, 110, 320, 529, 1386, 3324,4260, 24520),
                Species = c(370L, 640L, 680L, 640L, 1060L, 1200L,1400L, 1450L, 2525L))
modelo<-lm(log(Species,10)~log(Area,10),data=exemplo)

modelo_nls<-nls(Species~a*Area^z,start=list(a=1,z=0.25),data=exemplo)
linha<-data.frame(x=log10(seq(1,25000,100)),y=log10(predict(modelo_nls,newdata=data.frame(Area=seq(1,25000,100)))))
ggplot(data=exemplo,aes(x=log10(Area),y=log10(Species)) )  + geom_point() +
geom_abline(intercept = modelo$coefficients[1], slope = modelo$coefficients[2],linetype="dotted") +
geom_line(data=linha,aes(x=x,y=y),linetype="dashed")+        
xlab(label="Área(ha)") + ylab(label="Número de espécies")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to combine your two predicted lines into one data frame with an extra column indicating which model each row belongs to.

```
# Add model = 'A' to this data frame (I may have got A and B the wrong way round)
   linha <- data.frame(x = log10(seq(1,25000,100)),
                       y = log10(predict(modelo_nls,newdata=data.frame(Area=seq(1,25000,100)))),
                       model = 'A')

# Make data frame of line from modelo
lin2 <- data.frame(x = log10(seq(1,25000,100)), 
                   y = predict(modelo, newdata = list(Area = seq(1,25000,100))), 
                   model = 'B')

# Combine two models
combinedLines <- rbind(linha, lin2)
```

Then plot with model as an aesthetic

```
ggplot(data=exemplo,aes(x=log10(Area),y=log10(Species)) )  + geom_point() +
geom_line(data=combinedLines, aes(x=x,y=y, linetype = model))+        
xlab(label="Área(ha)") + ylab(label="Número de espécies")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it.

```
nlha <- data.frame(x=log10(seq(1,25000,100)),y=(predict(modelo,newdata=data.frame(Area=(seq(1,25000,100))))))
model_data <- cbind.data.frame(type=rep(c("A","B"),each=250),rbind(nlha,linha))
ggplot(data=exemplo,aes(x=log10(Area),y=log10(Species)) )  + geom_point() + geom_line(data=model_data,aes(x=x,y=y,linetype=type))+ xlab(label="Área(ha)") + ylab(label="Número de espécies")
```

I hope it helps.